# Ocultar aba - Java

Tags: java, jframe

Tenho uma programa com varias abas, assim testarei se o usuário é ADMIN, baseado nisso gostaria de ocultar/desabilitar algumas abas, já testei esses comandos e não desabilitam a janela:

```
private void SetAbasVisiveis( Usuario usuario){
   if(!usuario.getAdmin()){
        this.pnlMedicamentos.setVisible(false);
        this.pnlMedicamentos.setEnabled(false);
        this.pnlMedicamentos.setFocusable(false)
   }
}
```

Segue elementos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não percebi muito bem a sua questão. De acordo com o perfil do utilizador pretende habilitar ou não a aba? E até onde percebo, isto tem nada haver com o próprio Netbeans (na sua essência).

Comment: Qual o motivo de terem dado -1?

Comment: Não entendi porque do NetBeans no título

Comment: Se o Net beans é problema, bastam sugerir edição, não dar downvote

Comment: Só pra constar, não fui eu que dei downvote

Comment: Sim, eu sei, coloquei o NetBeans porque achei que ajudaria a responder por eu estar utilizando esse ambiente, mas muitos não entendem assim, já editei. Valeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema utilizando o seguinte comando:

Basta dizer o indice da aba, de `0 a N` (número de abas do projeto) e se tu queres ela habilitada = `true`, ou desabilitada = `false`

```
    private void setPermissoes(Usuario usuario){
        if(!usuario.getAdmin()){            
            this.TabbedPane.setEnabledAt(3, false);
            this.TabbedPane.setEnabledAt(2, false);
            this.TabbedPane.setEnabledAt(1, false);
        }
    }
```